# asp:DropDownList doesn't return correct value

Tags: asp.net

I have this `DropDownList` I bind it on the `codebehind`, when I put on `IsPostBack` always return null and when I put out always return the first value.
The code is this one:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    preencherAreas();
}
public void preencherAreas()
{

     try
     {
         string[] areas = areaLocal.Area.Split(';');
         List<Area> listAreas = new List<Area>();
         foreach (var a in areas)
         {

             listAreas.Add(new Area(a, a.Replace(" ", "_")));
         }
         selectArea.DataSource = listAreas;
         selectArea.DataTextField = "Text";
         selectArea.DataValueField = "Value";
         selectArea.DataBind();
     }
     catch (Exception)
     {
     }
 }
```

I try to catch the value wit `SelectedValue` and with `SelectedItem.Value` and the result is always the same that I said

Comment: When do you bind your Dropdown ? In Page_Load or Page_PreRender ? If in Page_Load, try to do it in Page_PreRender.

Comment: @KMarron i tried in both when i bind on `OnPreRender` return null

Comment: Can you add your DropDownList declaration in aspx page and its onSelectedItemChanged in your code behind ?